# If $F$ is finite over $L_1$ and $L_2$, is it also finite over $L_1 \cap L_2$?

Tags: field-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $L_1$, $L_2$ two subfields such that $F$ is finite over both $L_1$ and $L_2$. Is $F$ necessarily finite over the intersection $L_1 \cap L_2$?

Comment: Have you thought about this?

Comment: A necessary and sufficient condition is that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are finite over $L_1\cap L_2$.

Comment: @egreg Why not $L_1$ *or* $L_2$ being finite over $L_1\cap L_2$?

Comment: @Guest Yes, it's weaker.

Comment: I have thought about it, but I couldn't prove it nor find a counterexample.

Comment: Possible hint: WLOG, you can take $F'$ to be the field generated by $L_1$ and $L_2$ in $F$. Then, $F$ is finite over $F'$, so you can just ask about $F'$.